# Adding a new workplace

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add a new workplace on Facebook. My current employer has a Facebook page (/insironinformatika), but I can't add it as my employer (in the work and education panel). I tried so far:

1. Typing part of it's name ("Insiron"), but nothing.
2. Copying it's ID (257036897772224), but nothing.
3. Trying it's vanity URL ("insironinformatika"), but nothing.

Every time I press ENTER after typing something (something that's related to the name/ID/URL), I see a "The employer you entered is not valid." error.

How can I add it?

(Interesting fact, that I have a friend/colleague who has added it successfully)

Comment: Did you try entering full name and waiting for few seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the Facebook 'intellisense'/'auto-complete' isn't very responsive/exhaustive. In the employer field, try typing in the EXACT name of your Facebook page and hit 'enter'. It should show up.

<sup><sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13385046/4248931)</sup></sup>